# Am I allowed to cancel derivatives?

Tags: calculus

If I have $r$ as a function of $t$ and $\theta$ as  a function of $t$, then is this true? $$\frac{dr}{d\theta} = \frac{\,\,\,\,\displaystyle\frac{dr}{dt}\,\,\,\,\,}{\,\,\,\,\displaystyle\frac{d\theta}{dt}\,\,\,\,\,}$$

It would help me skip the step of writing $r$ as a function of $\theta$ in the problem I'm trying to solve, but I don't know if I'm "allowed" to do that kind of cancelling out...

Comment: btw I know what the chain rule is but this isn't the same thing.. right?

Comment: You are allowed to do this.  You get exactly the definition of the chain rule by multiplying both sides of your above equation by $\frac{d\theta}{dt}$.

Comment: ok thank you, make it answer so i can accept

Comment: Chain rule: if $f(x)=g(h(x))$, then $f'(x)=g'(h(x))h'(x)$. Applying proper substitutions, we conclude that cancellation is allowed since $dt$ approaches $(\ne 0$).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are allowed to do this.  You get exactly the definition of the chain rule by multiplying both sides of your above equation by $\frac{d\theta}{dt}$.  Many related rate problems are solved this way.

Comment: Can this be performed without knowing the function function(s) being differentiated?

Comment: Well, naturally, you would follow the rules like making sure to not divide by $0$, and unless the derivative is defined explicitly, you have to ensure the function is differentiable for the values of the variables you want to use.

Comment: Yes, and I also think you have to use the same function. I guess the expression in the OP question as is, is meaningless.